# Timeline of measurements of the electron's charge

Tags: experimental-physics, reference-request, bias

Where can I find a paper or reference that describes the timeline of measurements of the magnitude of the electron's electric charge.

For context, [Millikan's oil drop experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oil_drop_experiment) in 1908 determined the charge of the electron to be 1.59*10^(-19) C, which is lower than today's accepted value. Richard Feynman is quoted as [saying, in 1974,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oil_drop_experiment#Millikan.27s_experiment_as_an_example_of_psychological_effects_in_scientific_methodology) that subsequent experimental attempts to measure the charge were *biased* by Millikan's initial value:

> [...] *It's interesting to look at the history of measurements of the charge of an electron, after Millikan. If you plot them as a function of time, you find that one is a little bit bigger than Millikan's, and the next one's a little bit bigger than that, and the next one's a little bit bigger than that, until finally they settle down to a number which is higher.*
>
> *Why didn't they discover the new number was higher right away? It's a thing that scientists are ashamed of—this history—because it's apparent that people did things like this: When they got a number that was too high above Millikan's, they thought something must be wrong—and they would look for and find a reason why something might be wrong. When they got a number close to Millikan's value they didn't look so hard. And so they eliminated the numbers that were too far off, and did other things like that...*

Is there a reference that shows the temporal evolution of the electron's charge values? The most I've found is a statement that the values *did* change, but not what those values were.

Comment: I've heard a similar thing said about the history of estimates of the speed of light, although it was more extreme: one early result "anchored" several subsequent results on values that were significantly off...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If anyone's still reading this thread, here's a few more data points that appear to back Feynmann's interpretation.

[Erik Bäcklin, Nature vol 123](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v123/n3098/pdf/123409a0.pdf), no. 3098, p. 409 (1929): $1.59875 \cdot 10^{-19} \pm 0.004796 \cdot 10^{-19} $.

Wide error bar overlaps Millikan's.

[Gunnar Kellstrom, Phys. Rev. 1935](http://journals.aps.org/pr/pdf/10.1103/PhysRev.50.190): $1.60709  \cdot 10^{-19} \pm 0.011 \cdot 10^{-19} $.

Revises Millikan's value based on updated viscosity of air. Wide error bars!

[H.R. Robinson, 1937 Rep. Prog. Phys. 4 212](http://iopscience.iop.org/0034-4885/4/1/312): $4.803 \cdot 10^{-10} \, \text{esu} = 1.602 \cdot 10^{-19} \, \text{C}$

Concludes with a note added at the proof stage: "Backlin and Flemberg’s result, however, comes down to $4.778\cdot10^{-10}$--or very nearly to Millikan's 1917 value! This is a most unfortunate note on which to end the Report."

[image: Oil drop charge--historical reports]

Comment: I favorited this question two years ago in hopes of more information. Your necromancy does not go unappreciated. :)

Comment: Excellent research, thanks. And also a wonderful example of why open science is necessary. Millikan was quite ruthless in purging suspected outliers, it seems...

Answer (score 22):

The 16th (1995) edition of [Kaye and Laby](http://www.kayelaby.npl.co.uk/) includes the [following progression](https://uqu.edu.sa/files2/tiny_mce/plugins/filemanager/files/4250137/B6P1%20ch-2.pdf) of the accepted values for the charge of an electron. The first value "is essentially Milikan's oil drop value" and the second is "the 'X-ray grating' value". I couldn't find any more details about the actual experiments. The standard errors are often over-optimistic, indicating unexpected systematic errors; in Milikan's case this was due to an inaccurate value for the viscosity of air.

- 1.5911 ± 0.0024 [Birge, 1929]
- 1.60203 ± 0.00050 [Birge, 1942]
- 1.60210 ± 0.00002 [Dummond and Cohen, 1963]
- 1.602192 ± 0.000007 [Taylor et al, 1969]
- 1.6021892 ± 0.0000046 [Cohen and Taylor, 1973]
- 1.6021773 ± 0.00000049 [Cohen and Taylor, 1987]

[image]

Interestingly, this doesn't really seem to bear out Feynmann's assertion. However, it would be useful to see the progression of values between 1929 and 1942: e.g. from K&L 8th edition (1936).

Comment: A snippet from https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=VP9UAAAAMAAJ (1938) states "This series of experiments gave the value of the electron charge as 1.59 X 10-19 coulomb, the value which has been used until 1936, when a slight correction was discovered. The value now accepted is 1.60 X 10-19 coulomb."